# SSRS - jQuery Datepicker issue for Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, reporting-services, datepicker, ssrs-2008

The datepicker does not show up for SSRS datetime parameters in Chrome. I managed to download the project from this [Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504567/Print-button-Date-picker-in-SSRS-Reports-for-Non-I) and it works fine. However, when I add the same code to my solution, it does not work. I'm stumped. 
The only difference between the sample project and the file in my solution is that one is a website, and the other is a web application (datepicker works in the website). Reproducing the entire code below. Any suggestions would be welcome.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>View Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, form {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
            font-size: small;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmReportViewer" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="divMain">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer BackColor="#dee7f2" ID="rvREXReport" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="700px" Width="986px" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True" Style="display: table !important; margin: 0px; overflow: auto !important;" AsyncRendering="false" PageCountMode="Actual"></rsweb:ReportViewer>

        </div>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function pageLoad() {
            $(function () {
                $.browser.chrome = $.browser.webkit;
                //if ($.browser.chrome) {
                showDatePicker();
                //}
            });
        }

        function showDatePicker() {
            var parameterRow = $("#ParametersRowrvREXReport");
            var innerTable = $(parameterRow).find("table").find("table");
            var span = innerTable.find("span:contains('Start Date')");
            if (span) {
                var innerRow = $(span).parent().parent();
                var innerCell = innerRow.find("td").eq(1);
                var textFrom = innerCell.find("input[type=text]");
                innerCell = innerRow.find("td").eq(4);
                var textTo = innerCell.find("input[type=text]");
                $(textFrom).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                        $(textTo).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                });
                $(textFrom).focus(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(textFrom).datepicker("show");
                });
                $(textTo).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                        $(textFrom).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                });
                $(textTo).focus(function () {
                    $(textTo).datepicker("show");
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using Weirspm.Amp.Framework.Infrastructure.Security;


public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string _reportName;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _reportName = "SomeReport";
        this.Page.Title = _reportName;
        if ((!Page.IsPostBack))
        {

            // Set the report server URL and report path
            string _reportServerUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["REPORT_SERVER_PATH"];
            string _reportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["REPORT_SERVER_FOLDER_PATH"];
            string _userName = CryptoHelper.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportCredentialsUsername"]);
            string _pasword = CryptoHelper.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportCredentialsPassword"]);
            // Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote
            rvREXReport.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ServerReport serverReport = rvREXReport.ServerReport;
            rvREXReport.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials(_userName, _pasword);
            serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(_reportServerUrl);
            serverReport.ReportPath = _reportPath + _reportName;
            string userId = "1";
            List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter> { new ReportParameter("UserId", userId) };
            rvREXReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this code to work or figure out some other way to show the date picker in Chrome/non-IE browsers?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been so long, I don't really remember, and I don't have access to the code anymore. I think it worked when I tried a different version of jQuery, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Above code worked for me... Let me know if any one is facing any issue while using above code. It is not showing datepicker icon but when you click on date field it will open the calender.